# C++ taylor series estimation of initial value differential equation accuracy

Tags: c++, taylor-series

I was asked to use the taylor series method to estimate the initial value problem of `x(t)'= tx(t) + t^4, x(5) = 3`. I have to write code to display the estimates using the taylor series method by `0<=t<=5`.

I have been taught to start at `t=0`, use initial condition at `t=0` to find `x0`, and go up to `t=5` by `0.01` increments by calculating `x'', x''', etc` and finding the next `x` corresponding to `t+0.01`.

How can I do this process backwards in c++ as in starting at `t=5` and going increments down to 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop like this:

```
double t = 5.0;
while (t > 0.0) {
       /* Your Code of Taylor function */
       t = t -0.01;
}
```

This code starts with a t value of 5.0 and decrements t in 0.01 in each iteration of the loop. The loop ends when t value reaches 0.0

Comment: What I am trying to say is this a recursion that requires the previous term to calculate the next, I need term 1 to find 2, but I am not sure how to find term 1 if I was given the term 2. In this case, I was given t=5, and I need to find t=4.99 going backwards.

Comment: @B.Li this solution does what you want. what is the problem ?

Comment: In the taylor series of estimating differential equation answers, it is a recursion where the term xn+1 requires the term xn in its calculations. say I was given t0 = 1, then I can use t0 to find x0, then use x0 to find x1. If I was given xn+1 and I need to find xn, I am not sure how to retrace the steps to find the previous term in the recursion.

Comment: Do you have the recursive code of the Taylor function? Post this, please

Answer (score 1):

That's not a problem, what you need to concentrate on is the Taylor expansion of the solution, once you've done that it's only a matter of calculating the function for each value. To find the Taylor expansion you do it around `t=5` since you know `x(5)=3`, then you find `x'(5)` directly from the differential equation, and subsequent derivatives by differentiating both sides of the equation repeatedly. You find that the `t^4` term will eventually go away and the rest will result in a simple recursive formula.

```
#include <cstdio>

double c[] = { 3,
               625,
               500,
               300,
               120,
               24 };

double x(double t) 
{
    int j;
    double cc = 0;
    double cp = 0;
    double tj = 1;
    double s = 0;

    for(j=0; j<100; j++) {
        cc = (j-1)*cp + 5*cc;

        if( j < sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]) )
            cc += c[j];

        if( j > 0 )
            cc /= j;

        s += cc * tj;
        //printf("[%2d] %f %f\n", j, cc, s);

        tj *= (t-5);
    }

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    double t;

    for( t = 0.0; t<5.005; t+=0.01 )
        printf("%f %f\n", t, x(t));

    return 0;
}
```

The array `c` is terms that arise from the initial value and the derivatives of `t^4`. These terms vanish after `24`. To loop `100` times have been found empirically since the expansion seem to have converged then.